# What is meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am new here and want to know more about Meta Stack Overflow. I mean which type of discussion and post are posts here. Sorry for this question, but I don't know.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Its for discussing the site itself; bugs, feature requests, support questions etc

Comment: Read the help, about, and have a peruse through the questions and answers. You'll soon get used to it, or run away screaming.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from [About](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about)

> This site is for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites.

Meta Stack Overflow is a place where you ask questions about Stack Overflow and also about all other Stack Exchange. It is the Mother of all other Stack Exchange Site's Metas.

Here you can ask questions about stack overflow and other stack exchange sites, This is also a place where you ask **where to ask** (I mean. If you are not clear which stack exchange site to ask a question then ask here where to ask). You can also make feature requests for stack exchange sites and report bugs you have Noticed